# Use values from one row SELECT TOP 1 in another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I stacked with two queries, as I need one result table.
I have a complicated first query with cte table and some functions, which gives me a one row result like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Result1, Result2, Result3 
FROM  someTable
INNER JOIN antoherTable ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY...
```

Result table:

```
Result1,Result2,Result3
1,2,3
```

In the same procedure I have second SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Result 
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ..
WHERE ...
ORDER BY..

Result table:
Col1, Col2, Col3, Result
aa,bb,cc,5
aa,bb,cc,0
aa,bb,cc,2
aa,bb,cc,1
```

In some way, I need to mark rows that result is in results from first query (in this example last two rows).

I use SQL Server 2005. I tried add extra column called 'Marked' with 0/1 values, and put whole first query into CASE WHEN function.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Result,
CASE WHEN Result IN (SELECT TOP 1 Result1, Result2, Result3 ....)
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ..
WHERE ...
ORDER BY..
```

But it gives me an error:
*Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS*

It works only if I use one column, only Result1 like this:

```
CASE WHEN Result IN (SELECT TOP 1 Result1 ....)
```

I found some thread with that error message, and I tried also EXISTS function, but without any success.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for amateur question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` instead:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM . . .  -- your query here
                   WHERE x.Result IN (y.Result1, y.Result2, y.Result3)
                  )
      . . .
```

Note that `x` is an alias from the *outer* query, and `y` is an alias from the inner one.

You can also use `IN` and unpivot:

```
(CASE WHEN x.result IN (SELECT v.Result
                        FROM . . .  CROSS APPLY
                             (VALUES (Result1), (Result2), (Result3)) v(result
                       )
      . . .
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick tips. In first one, I'm not sure what replace instead of y. and how to get y.Result1, y.Result2... from one row SELECT TOP 1.. Is there any possiblity to put values Result1, Result2, Result3 in some one column Array before query, and use prepared array for IN function inside? For the second code - I don't know at all how to implement. Maybe easier will be just join somehow Result1, Result2, Result3 to result table?

Comment: @jeremy5 . . . As I explain in the question, `x` and `y` are just table aliases.  Use the appropriate table references for your columns.